# How to test if a disk has a valid `GPT` with `sgdisk`?

Tags: gpt

Is there a way to non-destructively test if a disk has a valid `GPT` with `sgdisk`, or, failing that, with some other scriptable command-line tool?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out that `sgdisk` "creates" a `GPT` in memory but doesn't *write* for the `--print` operation. So a straightforward way to test if there is an existing `GPT` is to `--print` twice and compare `GUID`s; as the `GUID` is randomly-generated, it is extremely unlikely to be the same in the case where `sgdisk` is creating an in-memory `GPT` (while it will match if `sgdisk` found a valid `GPT`).